# Number addition riddle

Tags: summation, arithmetic, puzzle

I got this math "riddle" in one of my math test, and I would love to know how to solve it.

If
$$S = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \ldots + 2015,$$
then a sum of
$$1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 2015 + 2016 + \ldots + 4030$$
is equal to: ?

I know the answer is  $2S + 2015^2$, but not how to get it. Could someone explain, please?

Comment: For the terms 2016 and up, write them as $2015+1, 2015+2, 2015+3, \dots$.

Comment: A related question would be to evaluate $2015+201S$ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&1+2+\cdots+2015+2016+\cdots+4030\\
=\:&S+(2015+1)+(2015+2)+\cdots+(2015+2015)\\
=\:&S+(1+2+\cdots+2015)+(\underbrace{2015+2015+\cdots+2015}_{2015\text{ times}})\\
=\:&S+S+2015\cdot2015\\
=\:&2S+2015^2
\end{align}
$$
If you want to find the value of $S$, you can do the following additional pairing:
$$
\begin{align}
S&=1+2+\cdots+2015\\
&=(2015+1)+(2014+2)+\cdots+(1009+1007)+1008\\
&=\underbrace{2016+2016+\cdots+2016}_{1007\text{ times}}+1008\\
&=1007\cdot2016+1008\\
&=2\,031\,120
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see, quite easy when I see it like this.. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the sum $S=\sum_{n=1}^{2015}\, n$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{4030} \,n&=\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \,n+\sum_{n=2016}^{4030} n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \,n+\sum_{n=1}^{2015}\, (n+2015)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \,n+\sum_{n=1}^{2015}\, n+2015\sum_{n=1}^{2015}\, 1\\\\
&=S+S+(2015)\times (2015)\\\\
&=2S+2015^2
\end{align}$$

As was to be shown.